# Pylab plotting with a table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making a pretty simple pandas/pylab bar plot with the following code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df2.plot(kind='bar', table=True)
plt.savefig('E:/chart.png')
```

The problem is that in the saved file *chart.png* the table is trimmed and only the first lines are visible. Is there any way to include the table in the image without having to make a subplot and render the table on a separate plot?

[image: The chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `bbox_inches='tight'`:

```
plt.savefig('chart.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

this should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I put the same line in the plot call, I should have put it in the savefig instead.

Answer (score 2):

tight_layout is your friend:

```
plt.tight_layout(rect=(0,0.1,1,1))
```

where rect is:

> interpreted as a rectangle
>       (left, bottom, right, top) in the normalized figure
>       coordinate that the whole subplots area (including
>       labels) will fit into. Default is (0, 0, 1, 1)

See my answer here (and the other one) if you want to tweak a bit more your table:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110283/3297428