# How can i change the "box" height of matblolib subplot and get the height of a matplotlib table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, height, subplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],'B':[1,2],'C':[1,2]})
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("title")
ax.set_xlabel('label')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
tab = ax.table(rowLabels=range(1,3),colLabels=['A','B','C'],cellText=df.values,loc='center',rowLoc='center')
plt.show()
##My doubt:
function_that_resize_the_box_height( function_that_get_the_table_height(tab) )
```

That is what i mean by 'box:

[image]

Comment: I did, the site says:"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility could be the opposite: set the size of the figure with `fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (5, 2.5))` and then set the `bbox` parameter of the table so that it fills the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],'B':[1,2],'C':[1,2]})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (5, 2.5))
ax.set_title("title")
ax.set_xlabel('label')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

tab = ax.table(rowLabels=range(1,3),colLabels=['A','B','C'],cellText=df.values,loc='center',rowLoc='center',
               bbox = [0, 0, 1, 1])

plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932072/matplotlib-table-formatting) for more information.